# Double arithmetic produces random number every time in C

Tags: c, math, double

I'm a beginner learning learning C for a class at university and was wondering why this piece of code always produce a random number and not 1 like I would expect.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double a, b = 32.5;
    a = 2 / 5 * (b - 30);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code it prints out a different random value every time:

```
-780835368
-1509625304
1267593528
```

are some of the results I've gotten. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, "%d" is expecting an integer type.

Comment: `printf("%f\n", a);` would work better. I am surprised the answer changes each time though - I would expect that you end up looking at the first four bytes of `a` which ought to be the same each time. Not so for the reverse - if you expect a longer type than you present, you might be looking at garbage on the stack.

Comment: I tired that but it only print 0.000000?

Comment: Of course - you do integer division `2/5` which is zero.

Comment: @JakeBarnby That's because your expression starts with 2/5, which equals 0.  Change it to 2.0 / 5.0 .  And read a book on C.

Comment: As a beginner, you should always compile your code with the compiler option `-Wall`, catching all warnings. Then you would have seen that there were incompatible types in the printf statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by attempting to print a double via the integer format specifier, `%d`. Use the floating-point specifier instead:

```
printf("%f\n", a);
```

---

> I tired that but it only print 0.000000?

Because of `2 / 5` -- that performs [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) and thereby results in `0`. Hence, `a` is assigned to `0`. You probably wanted `2.0 / 5.0` which performs true division.